# How to alignment photo in css grid

Tags: css, grid, gallery

I must create a gallery, I have a various amount of photo and I would like to have always adjusted pictures. How can I do this with CSS grid?

In screen I show you my example - I have 4 photos I would like to have mixed sizes and at the same time - have alignment. 
The problem is: I can't use simply css grid and arrange it properly, because I have also various amount of photo. So in one case, I have 4 photos, and another eg 15, and those photos always must be alignment. How can I do this? Maybe some library?

[image]

Comment: for better understanding provide your code what you have effort so, that you can achieve your solution.

Comment: Ok, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYGxwz, so in this case I have 4 photos, and everything works - photos are alignment. But if I remove one photo, I will have empty space, right? And that's the problem. I don't want have empty space, no matter how many photo I have. So I need have css grid which is variable depends on amount of photos and photos always must be alignment.

Answer (score 0):

...

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3,100px);
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "a a b"
    "a a b"
    "c d d";
  align-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.item1 {
  grid-area: a;
}
.item2 {
  grid-area: b;
}
.item3 {
  grid-area: c;
}
.item4 {
  grid-area: d;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item1">Objet 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Objet 2</div>
  <div class="item3">Objet 3</div>
  <div class="item4">Objet 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this solution isn't suitable for me, because it isn't reusable... What about when I will have only 3 photos? It will be still empty spaces, and I don't want this. I just wrote in my answer that I have a various amount of photos, depend on the case, so I mus t have something suitable to every situation.